# How to insert multiple objects in an array into a nested json in angular2+

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I am trying to add `multiple jsons` present in an `array` into a nested json layout, one by one in json format and not in `array` format.
I have the following values ->

```js
var abc = [];
abc = [{
  Client Code: {
    type: "string"
  }
}, {
  Virtual Account Number: {
    type: "string"
  }
}, {
  secret: {
    type: "string"
  }
}]

var pqr = {};
pqr = {
  Virtual Account Number Verification IN: {
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
      "properties": {

      },
      "type": "object"
    }
  }
}
```

I want the output as -

```js
output = {
    fields: [{
        "Virtual Account Number Verification IN": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "properties": {
              "Client Code": {
                "type": "string"
              },
              "Virtual Account Number": {
                "type": "string"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          secret: {
            type: "string"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

I tried it using this -

```js
for (var x = 0; x < this.pqr.length; x++) {
  this.abc['properties'] = this.pqr[x]
}
```

But it doesn't make any differencse.

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: your question is not clear, can you please elaborate it

Comment: if you tried this `this.abc['properties'] = this.pqr[x]` with the previous initialization of your abc variable which is an array, it will not work for sure. if you want to set a property named "properties" you have to work with objects, not arrays

Comment: @Techdive please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying incorrectly to assign values for your object. `Object` does not have `length` property, however, `array` has `length` property.
 Try this approach:

```
let abc = [{
    ClientCode: {
        type: "string"
    }
}, {
    VirtualAccountNumber: {
        type: "string"
    }
}, {
    secret: {
        type: "string"
    }
}];

let pqr = {
    "VirtualAccountNumber Verification IN": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "properties": {

        },
        "type": "object"
      }
    }
  };

pqr['VirtualAccountNumber Verification IN'].items.properties['ClientCode'] 
    =  abc[0].ClientCode;
pqr['VirtualAccountNumber Verification IN'].items.properties['VirtualAccountNumber'] 
    =  abc[1].VirtualAccountNumber;

let output = [];
output.push(pqr);
output.push(abc[2]);

console.log(output);
```